# How to convert string to a specific collation for a query

Tags: php, mysqli, collation

I am using php with mysqli to create a simple web project.
I am also using prepared statements.
At the variable that is to be binded, the input is greek language.

So when running the query through my php application I am getting this:

> Your input was "greek_characters_here"
>   Query error: Illegal mix of collations (greek_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (latin1_swedish_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='

What can I do to bypass this problem?

**Note:** I cannot change the databases collaction since I don't have the rights.

Answer (score 0):

In case you can't ALTER the Tables and set the collation, you could try the BINARY operator which is simply a shorthand version of COLLATE, Your statement would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE BINARY a = BINARY b;
```

Comment: It passed the query but no results came up. I've used 'mysqli_query($link, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");' and it worked. Should I answer my own question and check it?

Comment: It might be helpful to post the query (the original one, as well as the modified one).

Comment: But I haven't changed at all my query. The only thing I've added is this: `mysqli_query($link, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");`